# Dynamically add new property with any name to object

Tags: c#

Well I guess the title explains it all guys.

I am fairly new to dynamics world in c# and I am seeking for a way to do something like this:

```
public dynamic AddPropertyToObject(Foo f, string varPropName)
{
    f.Str = "Hello";
    dynamic dynObj = f;
    dynObj.createPropertyNameAndSetValue(varPropName, "World");
    return dynObj;
}
```

The problem is that an object shall be extended by a new property with any given name.

The object (in my example its Foo) is an entity generated from wsdl and therefore *it doesnt inherit from `ExpandoObject`*.

How could I still achieve the object to be extended?

createPropertyNameAndSetValue is just there to visualize that I am seeking for something like this: `dynObject.varPropName = "World";`

Btw, I am looking for a solution without PropertyInfo and all that stuff.

I am sorry if this question is a duplicate. Let me know in comments before downvoting and I'll remove it.

Comment: It would help to understand if web service is yours (IE the class definition is under your control), or it id from a WSDL your application is consuming.

Comment: The wsdl is from a another company, I cant change there anything plus some classes already inherit from base classes so there is no chance to derivate from ExpandoObject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add properties to just anything. You need a class that knows how to integrate with the `dynamic` type system, and that has someplace to store the extra properties that you add to it.

Take a look at [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Create an instance of it and then start setting properties on it.

From your comments, it sounds like you want to extend an existing type to support something similar. The documentation for `ExpandoObject` will still help you out; it talks about how it's implemented, so it'll help you implement it on your own. The Remarks section explains:

> If you want to define types that have their own dynamic dispatch semantics, use the [DynamicObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. If you want to define how dynamic objects participate in the interoperability protocol and manage DLR fast dynamic dispatch caching, create your own implementation of the [IDynamicMetaObjectProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.idynamicmetaobjectprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface.

So you'll either need to change your class to descend from `DynamicObject` (which implements `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` and does some of the grunt work for you), or you'll need to implement `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` yourself.

Keep reading the docs, and you'll find a link to an article called [Implementing Dynamic Interfaces](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=198161), which should help you decide which is better in your case (descending, or implementing the interface directly).

Comment: What do you mean? This works: `dynamic dynObj = f; dynObj.hello = "Hello"` and foo is not a ExpandoObject. However hello property is hardcoded. I do not need hardcoded things.

Comment: It'll compile, but it won't run. `dynamic obj = new DateTime(); obj.hello = "Hello";` throws a `RuntimeBinderException` "'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'hello'". You can't add new properties to an object unless the class supports it.

Comment: It works for me with Foo. DateTime is a struct not a class. Maybe therefore it doesnt work...

Comment: Let's test your theory. `dynamic obj = new MemoryStream(); obj.hello = "Hello";` Result? Another `RuntimeBinderException`: "'System.IO.MemoryStream' does not contain a definition for 'hello'". I'll say it again: you can't add new properties to an object unless the class supports it.

Comment: Ahhh dammit, my fault, I see now what I did wrong. I am sorry. You are right `obj.hello` wont work. Still the problem is still there how to add properties to to objects without ExpandoObject? Any ideas?

Comment: You can't, because .Net types are statically typed, which means their members are determine in compile-time (when they're created). The dynamic feature allows you to late bound members of any type, but to get full dynamic support, you have to use one of the types provided for it. `ExpandoObject` sounds exactly like what you're looking for, except it won't expand other types. Another thing you can do, is inherit `DynamicObject`, and create a class which "expand" other object (allows you to access the other object`s members, and assign new members)

Answer (score 0):

Workaround using composition. Taking "Foo" itself as a property of dynamic object in the extension method

```
public static object AddProperty<T>(this Object baseObject,string baseObjectPropertyName, string propertyName, T value)
{
    IDictionary<string, object> ob;
    if (baseObject is IDictionary<string, object>)
    {
        ob = baseObject as IDictionary<string, Object>;
    }
    else
    {
        ob = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
        ob.Add(baseObjectPropertyName, baseObject);
    }
    ob.Add(propertyName, value);
    return ob;
}


var foo = new Foo();
var goingTobeIgnored = string.Empty;
dynamic ob = foo.AddProperty("FooObject","Hello", "World")
            .AddProperty(goingTobeIgnored, "AnotherHello", "AnotherWorld");
```

Comment: Could you explain your code? Dont you lose aready added properties when you always create new ExpandoObject?

Comment: Modified code with which you can add more properties dynamically. Or, you can defer adding properties by collecting all the properties and values and pass them once

Comment: You can check something like "routedictionary". It takes an object as a constructor parameter and have it's properties as dictionary

Comment: Ok now I understand it. :)