# How to dynamically add entity properties using N-Tier Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dynamic, n-tier-architecture

I would like to know how to dynamically add an undetermined number of unmapped properties to an entity.  We are currently using a DataTable and dynamically adding columns and then binding that table to an UltraGrid; I would like to replicate that with an entity.  Please note that I am using the N-Tier Entity Framework (https://ntieref.codeplex.com/).

I could either dynamically create an entity with properties, or dynamically add properties to an existing entity that does not contain any mapped properties.  Each time the application runs, a different number of properties will be added, so I don’t need to permanently retain new/dynamic properties.  I want to be able to bind the EntitySet as a datasource for an UltraGrid; I will not be utilizing this entity for data modification directly, only accessing the state tracking.

I found a DynamicPropertyHelper class in the N-Tier Entity Framework library but am unable to determine what it is used for.

My entities already inherit from another class and thus cannot inherit from ExpandoObject.

Here are some related posts but I don’t think they are the answer(s) I’m looking for.
[Dynamically add new property with any name to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22269176/dynamically-add-new-property-with-any-name-to-object)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e9ebabd3-1423-48f5-a57b-cf1248117851/how-do-i-add-a-property-field-at-runtime-in-c?forum=Vsexpressvcs

I would like to think that entities have at least as much functionality as datasets…

I would appreciate any assistance, even if the answer is that it can’t be done.

Thank you.

Comment: You can probably do everything you want with `ExpandoObject`

Answer (score 1):

You can allow entities to support dynamic properties by overriding the protected methods `GetDynamicValue` and `SetDynamicValue`.

It’s up to you how values of dynamic properties are stored and exposed through the WCF data contract. However, you can use `DynamicPropertyHelper` to do this job. The helper uses binary serialization and base-64 encoding to store all dynamic properties as an XML string. Here is a sample:

```
partial class MyEntity
{
    [DataMember]
    [SimpleProperty]
    private string DynamicContent
    {
        get { return _dynamicContent; }
        set
        {
            if (_dynamicContent != value)
            {
                OnPropertyChanging("DynamicContent", value);
                var previousValue = _dynamicContent;
                _dynamicContent = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DynamicContent", previousValue, value);
            }
        }
    }
    private string _dynamicContent;

    protected override object GetDynamicValue(string propertyName)
    {
        return DynamicPropertyHelper.GetDynamicProperty(DynamicContent, propertyName);
    }

    protected override void SetDynamicValue(string propertyName, object value)
    {
        var dynamicContent = DynamicContent;
        DynamicPropertyHelper.SetDynamicProperty(ref dynamicContent, propertyName, value);
        DynamicContent = dynamicContent;
    }
}
```

You can then simply set and get dynamic property values via the entity’s indexer:

```
MyEntity x = ...;
x[“DynamicPropertyName”] = dynamicPropertyValue;
```

Comment: I appreciate your response, but I’m still not sure if your suggested solution works for my situation.  What I’m getting seems to be a serializable dictionary property, not individual properties that have been added to my entity.

Comment: The end result using the DynamicPropertyHelper yields only one property, that holds many values; I’m thinking this one property is a dictionary.  When binding the MyEntity entityset to an UltraGrid, the property names appear as columns, so there is a column with the name DynamicContent and the content of the column is XML; but what I’m looking for are multiple columns representing the multiple “dynamic properties” I have added.

Comment: Just curious…  The DynamicPropertyHelper seems to mimic the serialization of a Dictionary.  Will you please provide a more comprehensive description of what the DynamicPropertyHelper is doing?  Thank you.

Comment: Your assumptions are correct, the DynamicContent property is used to store multiple name-value-pairs within a single string for transmission between client and server – it should not be displayed in your grid as it is private. DynamicPropertyHelper does the job of storing and reading these name-value-pair-collection to and from xml. You can access the individual values via the entities indexer as shown above.

Comment: If you're interested in details of DynamicPropertyHelper - it's just some lines of code and it's all open source: 
https://ntieref.codeplex.com

Comment: Your comments have been educational.  The proposed solution would be helpful in certain situations where the need is to store data without trying to bind the data, but not in mine because I want to dynamically add individual properties just like the original properties.  Since I can't dynamically create the entity I need to bind, I am utilizing a workaround by populating a DataSet DataTable to bind to the UltraGrid instead.

Comment: @LorenNicole If I understand correctly you’re using dynamic properties on client-side only for display/binding purpose. This is in contrast to dynamic properties (key-value-pairs) provided by the framework which are meant for transmission from client to server and vice versa.